# How to convert a hexadecimal value represented by a char?

Tags: c++, hex

I have an unsigned char array where I would like to parse its first four elements as HEX values.

I receive and `unsiged char array a[]`,whose content is this

```
for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  SerialUSB.print(" Index : ");
  SerialUSB.print(i);
  SerialUSB.print(" ,Unsigned Char ");
  SerialUSB.print( a[i]);
  SerialUSB.print(", CHAR ");
  SerialUSB.print( (char) a[i]);
  SerialUSB.println();
}

Index:0  ,Unsigned Char 98, CHAR b
Index:1  ,Unsigned Char 49, CHAR 1
Index:2  ,Unsigned Char 53, CHAR 5
Index:3  ,Unsigned Char 57, CHAR 9
Index:4  ,Unsigned Char 55, CHAR 7
Index:5  ,Unsigned Char 56, CHAR 8
Index:6  ,Unsigned Char 85, CHAR U
Index:7  ,Unsigned Char 55, CHAR 7
Index:8  ,Unsigned Char 56, CHAR 8
Index:9  ,Unsigned Char 85, CHAR U
Index:10 ,Unsigned Char 55, CHAR 7
Index:11 ,Unsigned Char 56, CHAR 8
Index:12 ,Unsigned Char 85, CHAR U
```

How can I get the HEX value of the first four elements of array `a[]`

```
inHex[0] = 0xB; // 0xB = 11
inHex[1] = 0x15; // which should come from having concatenated the values `a[1]= '1'` algong with `a[2]='2'`
inHex[3] = 0x9; // which should  be the char value of a[3] in HEX
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you clearly say what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Pavel, I want the first four elements of array `a` as three different HEX numbers

Comment: How does b map to 17 (11 in hexadecimal)? Don't you mean hexadecimal B, which is decimal 11?

Comment: @molbdnilo yes that is what I mean exactly

Comment: How do four bytes map to three numbers? How does 98 map to 0xB to map to 11? What is U supposed to map to? Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @ndarkness still not clear what you mean. Number is a number, it's not hex or anything, it's a number. Show sample input and sample output?

Comment: @Pavel I have updated the post

Comment: B is still not 0x11, but 0xB is 11. Already, without any conversion. Unclarity remains.

Comment: @EJP I would like to have B not b so that I can convert it to 0xB which is 11 in decimal

Comment: So why do you keep saying 0x11? Please stop it. And what are the answers to my other three questions?

Comment: @ndarkness I totally don't get what you are trying to do even when you updated your question. Can you write something clear, without leaving as guessing what is `a` etc?!

Comment: You have char * a = "b159 ... ", why then you say `a[2]='2'` ? Do you wan to get 4 different integers for each of `0xb`, `0x1`, `0x5`, `0x9`?

Comment: @Pavel thanks for replying, I would like to have three different integers coming from the received `unsigned char a[]`, `0x11`, `0x15` and `0x9`

Comment: `inHex[0] = 0x11; // which should come from having converted toHEX( (char) a[0] )` - this is complete mess, nothing makes sense. it's not to hex, but from hex, result of toHex is a string, if you want to get integers then it's from hex. `b` or 'B' if treated as a hex digit means `11`, or `0xb` if written to hex.

Comment: @Pavel, thanks, I have updated the post. I tried to say in the above comment, each time that I get a `b` I would interpreate it as the HEXadecimal representation `B` for the decimal value `11`

Comment: @ndarkness why is that 'b' becomes `0x11`!? Do you understand yourself? Why is that second 0x15 is formed by strcat(a[1],a[2])?

Comment: @ndarkness `b I would interpreate it as the HEXadecimal representation B` - what is the difference? `0xb ` == 0xB

Comment: @Pavel, sorry I was a mistaked, the `b` should not become `0x11` but `11` in decimal

Comment: @Pavel, there is no difference, what you say is right and what I would like to have. Regarding to the second, it is not formed yet, I the problem I have is that the HEX valu that I want `0x15` is stored in the unsigned char array `a[]` in two values `a[1]= 1` = 10 and `a[2]=5` = 05

Comment: @ndarkness see my answer, it should do the conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get integer value from a hex digit (where hex digit is any character from this set: `0123456789abcdefABCDEF`):

```
int fromHex(char c)
{
    if (c>='0' && c<='9')
        return c-'0';
    if (c>='a' && c<='f')
        return 10+(c-'a');
    if (c>='A' && c<='F')
        return 10+(c-'A');
    return -1; // unexpected char
}
```

this way if you have char a[] = "abcd", you'll get {11, 11, 12, 14} for each of the chars.

Then to get integers from you your first 4 chars:

```
inHex[0] = fromHex(a[0]);
inHex[1] = fromHex(a[1]) * 16 + fromHex(a[2]);
inHex[2] = fromHex(a[3]);
```

[Sample code](http://ideone.com/FVtrQh):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fromHex(char c)
{
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        return c - '0';
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')
        return 10 + (c - 'a');
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
        return 10 + (c - 'A');
    return -1; // unexpected char
}

int main()
{
    char a[] = "b159";
    int inHex[3];
    inHex[0] = fromHex(a[0]);
    inHex[1] = fromHex(a[1]) * 16 + fromHex(a[2]);
    inHex[2] = fromHex(a[3]);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", inHex[0], inHex[1], inHex[2]);
    printf("0x%x 0x%x 0x%x\n", inHex[0], inHex[1], inHex[2]);
}
```

output:

```
11 21 9
0xb 0x15 0x9
```

Comment: To get the *value* of a *hex* character.

Comment: I am commenting on the imprecision of your first sentence. I am aware of what the function does.